# Book printout of questions

Tags: feature-request

Are there any plans on ordering a set of questions to be printed out and delivered in book format such as wikipedia has planned to do?

Answer (score 4):

Your prayers have been answered long ago: http://www.stackprinter.com/

http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=2836&service=meta.aviation.stackexchange

You can use the site to print the questions one by one into PDF files and then merge the files into a booklet.

Comment: Wow... I never realized how terrible it is to read hyperlinked documents with all the links converted into footnotes. I think I just had a bad acid flashback to college cross-referencing bibliographies.

Comment: @voretaq7 well, if you don't like it you could add `prettylinks=false` to the querystring like [this](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=2836&service=meta.aviation.stackexchange&prettylinks=false)

Comment: Broken link.. they changed the order of meta in the API response. Should be corrected in:
http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=2836&service=aviation.meta.stackexchange

Answer (score 0):

None I'm aware of.

[The Stack Exchange network licenses user submissions under CC:BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) though, so as long as you [properly attribute](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) each post you're putting in your collection there doesn't appear to be anything else standing in the way of such a project.

Organizing such a book would be a significant challenge - even the taxonomy of tags doesn't really do a *good* job of putting questions/answers into useful, indexable categories (at least IMHO).

Comment: True. But if a user could select specific questions and get them printed out I think it would be an awesome reference.